# dataRender in jqPlot ASP.NET from an AJAX Request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqplot

I am trying to render a jqPlot bar chart from an AJAX request and I can't get it to work.

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var ajaxDataRenderer = function (url, plot) {
   var ret = null;
   $.ajax({
      // have to use synchronous here, else returns before data is fetched
      async: false,
      url: url,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
         ret = data;
      }
   });
   return ret;
};

var jsonurl = "WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld";

plo12 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl, {
   title: 'AJAX JSON Data Renderer',
   dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
   seriesDefaults: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
         // Put a 30 pixel margin between bars.
         barMargin: 30,
         // Highlight bars when mouse button pressed.
         // Disables default highlighting on mouse over.
         highlightMouseDown: true
      },
      pointLabels: { show: true }
   },
   axes: {
      xaxis: {
         renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
      },
      yaxis: {
         // Don't pad out the bottom of the data range.  By default,
         // axes scaled as if data extended 10% above and below the
         // actual range to prevent data points right on grid boundaries.
         // Don't want to do that here.
         padMin: 0
      }
   },
   legend: {
      show: true,
      location: 'e',
      placement: 'outside'
   }
});
```

And my `WebService1.asmx` looks like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "[[2],[7],[14]]";
    }
}
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013650/jqplot-does-not-show-ajax-data) solution, but I am new to this and I can't figure out what my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this JQplot library via GWT. Make sure you have loaded the .JS files like jquery.jqplot,bar renders and so on..I think it will work or I might be wrong if you have already checked this.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that in the link to a solution you provide there is `/` in front of the jsonurl String. This might as well be it.

This might be also seen looking by the url of the requests you are sending, for example, in a `firebug` console.

Otherwise can you double-check that the method returns anything? Just run it without the graph and output whatever it gives to the console.

Other than that I see no problems in the `js` code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with setting ret = [data]

jqPlot expects an object in array format to render the charts.

Thanks